# Is it safe to use firebase anonymous authentication in Ionic App?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I want to develop an Ionic app for android and ios using firebase backend.

Requirement:
1. I want to use anonymous authentication silently so that user does not have to be worry about login.
2. I just want to display list of some items on the home page using Firestore api.

Question/Problem:
1. How does firebase will get to know that only the my app using the firestore get api.
2. If I am storing api credentials/secrets in my android app and if other user somehow knows these credentials, will that person be able to use api on behalf of my credentials and I will not be able to track the usage.

Top Level:
If someone know my firebase api credentials/secrets, will that person be able to utilize my firebase quota in case I am using firebase anonymous authentication.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings you use to initialize the Firebase SDK are not "secrets".  It's all very much public information that identifies your app from all the other Firebase apps out there.  Every Firebase app has a similar set of public data.  Once you publish your app, you should assume that everyone is able to see that data.

This means that anyone can use that data.  That's why it's important to use Firebase Authentication along with security rules to make sure that people logged in can only make use of whatever resources you specify.  That's the only way to lock down the data in your Firebase project.  If you are concerned about security, then you should be thinking about your security rules from the very beginning.

Comment: Thanks, If I am using anonymous authentication then also one anonymous user will be created. Will we able to know that anonymous user is created from our app?

Comment: No, it's not possible to know.  They could have invoked the command from the browser console without your code knowing any differently. They could have also used the Firebase Auth REST api directly with the API key that all apps expose (which is not really an API key so much as a unique project identifier).  Again, you should look into using security rules, possibly along with Cloud Functions, to prevent or mitigate the worst things that could happen.

Comment: Okay then if a hacker knows my credentials for firebase he/she can utilize my firebase quota from their app because if I have enabled authentication by emai id and password, he/she can also store email id and password from their app and I will not get to know whether the user is registering from my app or other app? then how we can prevent other users not to use our quota

Comment: As I said, there's nothing private about this information, so it's not "credentials".  The API key is in no way authenticating or authorizing use of any APIs.  It's merely identifying your project.  You can't stop people from using your app when it's published, nor can you stop people from using the APIs that power your app.  If you think there is abusive behavior in your app, report it to Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/